# Android NN to TF-Lite Conversion

Tags: neural-network, nnapi

Am trying to run my custom Neural Network model using Android NN API from TF-Lite.
there are mismatch with outputs between Android NN and TF-Lite. To cross check my Android NN Model, i want to convert Android NN model to TF-Lite. Is there any way ?

Comment: I developed a project to convert TF-Lite model to Android NNAPI, maybe it can help you to understand how to work with TF-Lite flatbuffer model.
https://github.com/alexst07/neural-network-transpiler

Comment: I am curious. Why id it either-or? You can use TFLite on Android and call `tfliteOptions.setUseNNAPI(true)`, can't you?